# Factorization Structures on the category of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, set-theory

In the category ${\bf Set}$, there are precisely $4$ $(E,M)$-factorization structures, namely

1. $(Iso,Hom)$;
2. $(Hom,Iso)$;
3. $(Epi,Mono)$;
4. $(\{e: X \to Y \mid X=\emptyset \implies Y =\emptyset\},\{g: X \to Y \mid \, g \in Iso({\bf Set}) \,\, or \,\, g: \emptyset \to Y\})$.

How can I find a proof of this fact? Or how to prove it?

Comment: Are you referring to this notion? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+factorization+system

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to it. However, see The Joy of Cats for a complete definition of $(E,M)$-structured category

Comment: Here are some hints. Suppose that there is some morphism in the left class which is not surjective. What can we deduce about an arbitrary morphism in the right class using the orthogonality property? Symmetrically if there is a morphism in the right class which is not injective.

Comment: I'm not sure of your hints. Actually, the last factorization I gave does not respect your hints

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "does not respect [my] hints"... It's a case disjunction and I wanted to explain how to start. I added an answer giving more details even if there are still gaps to fill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will asume known the following:

1. Given an orthogonal factorization system $(E,M)$, we have $M = E^{⊥}$ (the class of morphisms with the right lifting property against all morphisms in $E$) and dually $E = {}^{⊥}M$ (the class of morphisms having the left lifting property against all morphisms in $M$). Hence, an orthogonal factorization system is determined by its left class alone, or alternatively by its right class alone.
2. If $(E,M)$ and $(E',M')$ are two orthogonal factorization systems with $E ⊆ E'$ and $M ⊆ M'$, then actually $(E,M) = (E',M')$. This is because $E ⊆ E'$ is equivalent to $M' = E'^{⊥} ⊆ E^{⊥} = M$.

---

Suppose there is a map $f : A→B$ in the left class which is not surjective.

*Claim.* For all $g : X→Y$ in the right class, if there is a morphism $A→X$, then $g$ is a bijection.

*Proof.* Let $b ∈ B\setminus f(A)$. We can assume that the map $A→X$ is constant (if there exists a map, there exists a constant map). Under this additional assumption, for all $y ∈ Y$, there exists a function $u : B→Y$ sending $b$ to $y$ and making the following square commute.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> X\\
@VfVV @VVgV\\
B @>u>> Y
\end{CD}$$

Our assumption that $g$ is in the right class implies that there is a unique map $B→X$ making the two triangles commute. In particular, there is a unique $x ∈ X$ such that $g(x) = u(b) = y$. $\square$

There are two cases: (1) $A=∅$ and (2) $A≠∅$. In case (1), there is always a morphism $A→X$, so every map in the right class is a bijection and we have your 2nd factorization system. In case (2), the right class is included in the right class of your 4th factorization system. If for *all* $f$ not surjective in the left class, we are in case (2), this means that the left class is included in the left class of your 4th factorization system (all maps $∅→B$ in the left class need to be surjective, so $B=∅$). Conclusion: if there is some morphism in the left class which is not surjective, the factorization system is either your 2nd one or your 4th one.

---

*Claim.* If there is some $f : A→B$ in the right class which is not injective, then morphisms in the left class are bijections and the factorization system is your 1st one.

*Proof.* Let $b ∈ B$ be such that $|f^{-1}(b)| ≥ 2$. Let $g : X→Y$ be a morphism in the left class. Given any map $X→f^{-1}(b)$, complete the square below by sending every element of $Y$ to $b$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> A\\
@VgVV @VVfV\\
Y @>>> B
\end{CD}$$

By our assumption, there is a unique map $Y→A$ making the two triangles commute. The commutativity of the lower triangle means it is a map $Y→f^{-1}(b)$. Thus, $g$ induces a bijection $f^{-1}(b)^Y → f^{-1}(b)^X$, and since $|f^{-1}(b)| ≥ 2$, this means $g$ is bijective. $\square$

---

The last possibility is if all morphisms in the left class are surjections and all morphisms in the right class are injections. In this case it is your 3rd factorization system.

Comment: I have some questions concerning your answer: you say that if $f: A \to B \in E$ is not surjective, then for any $g: X \to Y \in M$ and $u: A \to X$, it follows that $g$ is a bijection. Why? Furthermore, in case $A=\emptyset$, the right class consists of isomorphisms. Why? And how to deduce that $Hom(**Set**) \subseteq E$? Can you write a detailed answer, clarifying all these non-immediate parts? Your whole answer has problems of this sort.

Comment: @TheWanderer Hi. I added some explanations. I admit this was more intended at first as a guide to help you make a full proof, rather than something very detailed. When faced with something of this sort, you should probably try to visualize examples: for instance, consider the inclusion $f : \{1\} → \{1,2\}$ and suppose it's in the left class. (cont.)

Comment: What can we deduce? Well, to deduce something we need to apply the lifting property, so we need commutative squares... what is a commutative square with $f$ as the top morphism? It' a map $g : X→Y$, a point $x ∈ X$ and a point $y ∈ Y$ (do you see why?). What does the lifting property say? It says that this $y$ has a unique antecedent. Once you get this, you try to see how you can generalize, etc. I'm not sure the proof above can really help with these things...

Comment: I do not understand the last part of the proof of the claim  If there is some $f: A \to B$ in the right class which is not injective, then morphisms in the left class are bijections and the factorization system is your 1st one. I suppose that you are also assuming $g$ surjective, right? Indeed, in this case, the correspondence $u \in f^{-1}(b)^X \to d_u \in f^{-1}(b)^Y$ is clearly a bijection. Now, how does $|f^{-1}(b)| \ge 2$ imply that $g$ is bijective?

Comment: @TheWanderer No, I don't assume $g$ is surjective. It is *any* function in the left class and we see that it induces a bijection $f^{-1}(b)^Y → f^{-1}(b)^X$. Define $O := f^{-1}(b)$, we suppose $|O|≥2$. To show that it implies $g$ is bijective, try to understand what the map $O^g : O^Y → O^X$ looks like: it takes a function $e : Y→O$ and restrict it to the image of $g$.

Comment: From that description, we get (1) if $g$ is not surjective, then $O^g$ is not injective since it will forget some information (you can build two different functions $Y→O$ equal on the image of $g$) and (2) if $g$ is not injective, then $O^g$ is not surjective since you will impose some non-trivial constraints on $O^g(e)$, namely that $O^g(e)(x) = O^g(e)(y)$ if $g(x) = g(y)$. (So that not all functions $O→X$ can be of the form $O^g(e)$.)

Comment: It's linked to something called Stone duality... I just record that here but it's not necessary to the problem. Let $\newcommand{\End}{\operatorname{End}}\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}\End(O)$ be the monoid of functions $O→O$. An $\End(O)$-set is a set equipped with an action of $\End(O)$. There is a special $\End(O)$-set, $O$, and the functor $X ↦ O^X$ is a contravariant functor from $\Set$ to $\End(O){-}\Set$. This functor has an adjoint which sends an $U ∈ \End(O){-}\Set$ to $O^U$, the set of morphisms $U→O$. Indeed, we have $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(U,O^X)≅\Hom(X,O^U)$.

Comment: If $|O|≥2$, then this functor $X ↦ O^X$ is actually fully faithful.

Comment: I just noticed, I wrote above "not all functions $O→X$ can be of the form $O^g(e)$" but it should be "not all functions $X→O$".

Comment: I said something false above. I should not have considered only the endomorphisms of $O$, we need to take *all* the operations $O^{α} → O$ instead of just for $α=1$. Otherwise there are ultrafilters and $X ↦ O^X$ is not fully faithful...